Could this glassy "Amber-Like" polymer used to store DNA be exposed to sunlight?
An interesting article, that I came across today, talked about the ongoing research into storing DNA at room temperature essentially with glassy "amber-like" polymers. Before talking about the polymer, it looked into current methods to store DNA at room temperature.

But DNA decays in days at room temperature, so it is stored today at cryogenic temperatures, which requires energy and special equipment. “If I wanted to send DNA on a mission to Mars or collect samples in rural Africa, that’s not going to work,” says James Banal, cofounder of Cache DNA, which is developing a new biomolecule storage technology. For room-temperature storage, he and others have previously encapsulated DNA in silica particles and calcium phosphate crystals. This process takes days because water-loving DNA needs to be dissolved in organic solvents using surfactants, which are then removed via drying.

This is clear, but from here own, they talk about an alternative technique of storing of DNA in a polymer(a hard polystyrene-based thermoset polymer), which is describe as

The team made special polycation molecules composed of a water-loving side and an oily water-repellent one. Charges on the molecule bound to DNA and quickly transferred it from water to a solvent containing styrene monomers. Heating the solution created a glassy polymer block containing DNA.

The article describes it as glassy or "amber-like", essentially indicating that its not opaque. Now my question remains, that upon exposure to sunlight, would it allow UV light to penetrate and damage the stored DNA? Or would the "amber-like" properties allow for the blocking of UV light?
I do understand that the article is(could be) an oversimplification of the concept, but if such storage of DNA in polymers is possible, would it mean that polymer could be exposed to sunlight without any worry(especially if you want to collect samples in rural Africa, as aforementioned)?

At room T does not implicitly mean exposed to light.

Yes, I agree. But I wanted to know whether exposure to light in any circumstances affects the DNA.
